# A suggestion for improving the quality of OP's titles

Tags: feature-request, title

When the OP asks a question, the title box contains the hint

> what's your language learning question?

so the OP duly types in his question:

> What's the difference between these two sentences?

This as an appropriate response to the hint, but it's about as much use as [substitute your favourite metaphor here].

Would it be worth while changing the hint to say something like

> What's your question about?

or something suggesting (as briefly as possible) that the title should help people with the same question to **find** it.

So, two questions: should it be changed, and if so, what should the new hint be?

Comment: Related: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2630/

Comment: @ColleenV: Nice! A "Not sure? Check this link" link next to the title box would be great!

Comment: Well, the intention is nice, but I doubt your proposed change will do anything useful. I imagine next time they see the hint (provided that they take the hint into account writing a bad title) they'd type "two sentences I have problems with".

Comment: Needs something like "include in your title the word(s) or language issue you are asking about". The link is good but includes a lot of writing tips that are not related to getting key words and issues into the title. Even if someone can or will read through it.

Comment: Something like "summarize your overall inquiry in a single sentence, framed as a question, ending with a question mark"? The problem will be, of course, that no matter *what* the hint says, people "just want to ask" their question, and don't *want* to our a lot of thought and effort in beforehand. And, sometimes, it's difficult to summarize a question well. The antidote, of course, is for high-rep users to edit their questions after the fact, but the comes with its own slew of issues, including the misplacement of responsibility, and territoriality displayed by many OPs.

Comment: Why not include sample question titles in the prompt?

Comment: I like @John Clifford's suggestion. It might be good to have a sample `DO & DON'T`. For instance: _Don't give your question a title that could apply to hundreds of questions, like "What is the difference between these two sentences." Instead, be more specific; for example: "What is the difference between 'carry the load' and 'carry the weight'?"_

Comment: This is an issue that would probably be best handled on meta.SE. Every single site has the same format here: "what's your [short site description] question?" We've actually discussed this on meta here before, thought I can't seem to find the question now. I like @J.R.'s idea that we could edit the prompt, similar to how moderators can edit sections of the Help page. I'd upvote if you posted to MSE :)

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, writing titles is *hard*. Most people are bad at it. Most people are also bad at writing email subjects and similar things. I really don't think there's a quick fix for this; it's simply a life skill that some have, and some don't.

A good title is interesting, concise, covers what's most important, and distinct. Memorable and evocative, in other words. That's not something that a line or two of prompting is gonna help much with, because those important qualities are all fairly subjective, so it's really more of a knack to get something you can put in a short how-to.

Comment: Agreed, but even no hint at all would be better than a clear instruction to do the wrong thing.